# What is the relationship between hbase and google cloud bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm reading google bigtable document: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs

there are so many hbase, What is the relationship between hbase and google cloud bigtable?

is bigtable based on hbase?

Answer (score 3):

As Don Branson said, HBase was based on the Bigtable WhitePaper.  When Cloud Bigtable launched, the open source client libraries of Cloud Bigtable implemented the same set of interfaces as the HBase client libraries.

HBase and Bigtable have similar models, so the APIs are quite similar.  This convergence of APIs helps Cloud Bigtable code to be vendor neutral, and would allow you to port your application elsewhere, or port your HBase application to Cloud Bigtable.

Answer (score 2):

The original Bigtable was designed and built at Google for internal use. There's a paper that captures the design as it existed in 2006, [Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf).

[Hbase](https://hbase.apache.org) is an Apache project based on that paper. So, it's offered as a product.

Google now offers a big table database-as-a-service. "[Cloud Bigtable is Google's NoSQL Big Data database service](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/)."

The Google paper says,

> We have described Bigtable, a distributed system for
>   storing structured data at Google. Bigtable clusters have
>   been in production use since April 2005, and we spent
>   roughly seven person-years on design and implementation
>   before that date. As of August 2006, more than sixty
>   projects are using Bigtable.

Bigtable was designed and built at Google, and according to the paper, is the basis of "more than sixty projects" as of 2006. It could be that their cloud offering is instead based on HBase, but it seems more likely to me that they're using a descendant of their original Bigtable, not HBase. I don't see anything that says for certain, though.

Comment: I'd say HBase is the open-source BigTable. The paper was based on the already-existing BigTable implementation, so the "creation order" is BigTable -> WhitePaper -> HBase. Similarly you have Cloud Spanner -> WhitePaper -> CockroachDB